# How to change default signature_def using Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

How do I change the `signature_def` key when training and serving a model built using `DNNClassifier` Estimator in `Tensorflow`?

Using the `saved_model_cli` tool I see the default is `predict`. I would like to change this.

I'm saving the model to be served with the following function:

```py
  def save_serving_model(self,estimator):
      ''' 
      To run a quick check:
      saved_model_cli run --dir /path/to/mode/ --tag_set serve --signature_def predict --input_exprs="Headline=['some text'];Description=['some more text']"
      '''
      feature_placeholder = {'Headline': tf.placeholder('string', [1], name='headline_placeholder'),
        'Description': tf.placeholder('string', [1],name='description_placeholder')}
      serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_placeholder)
      estimator.export_savedmodel(self.serving_model_name, serving_input_fn)
```